# Upload a photo on Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, upload, facebook-php-sdk, photo

I'm making a website that users can upload photos to facebook via PHP Facebook api.

if a user attach a photo it should go to their album directly.
It's weird that it used to work but now it's not working.

here's the code

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$userPhoto  = $_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"];
```

`$fb_photoUpdate = $facebook->api('/$fb_id/photos/', 'post', array('source'=>'@'.realpath($userPhoto), 'message'=> 'photo uploaded successfully!'));`

$fb_id is facebook user id. I save user's id in database when they first login on my website. Also, I save their access token.

I want to use &fb_id instead of /me. 
Is there any way to make this code work? Should I add access token there?

Please help me and Thanks in advance.

Plus, I've tried like this

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true); ?>
```

`<script language="javascript">alert('1');</script>`

```
<?php try { ?>
<script language="javascript"> alert('2');</script>
<?php   $fb_photoUpdate = $facebook->api('/$fb_id/photos/', 'post', array('source'=>'@'.realpath($userPhoto), 'message'=> $_POST['posting'])); ?>
<script language="javascript"> alert('3');</script>
<?php }
```

But, All I got was alert 1, alert 2. There was no alert 3 and also i didn't get any errors from console.

Comment: Why you want to use `fb_id instead of /me` ?

Comment: In fact, I tried /me but it also didn't work. I wanted to use $fb_id because.. what if there's no facebook account logged in when a user wants to upload a photo to Facebook through my website. if that happens it's like there's no /me at that time. Is it wrong? I'm kind of new to using this facebook SDK so I assumed like that.

Comment: _“Should I add access token there?”_ – well do you _have_ an access token for the current user?

Comment: Yes I do have the current user's access token. I save that when a user authorizes us to get their facebook information.

Answer (score -1):

try changing `$userPhoto  = $_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"];` to `$userPhoto  = $_FILES["pic"];`

If not, are there any error codes you can share with us?

Comment: I changed the code that you told me. But it didn't work. I added more explanation. Thank you.